# Where to wire usb shield output on breakout

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-c

Apologies if this is rather obvious but I am very much new to circuitry and most answers I have found are about designing new products.

I have a [USB Type C female receptacle](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4090) that I would like to attach to my keyboard. The keyboard PCB has a USB 2.0 pin out labeled S, G, D+, D-, V. I am wondering where I should attach the S pin (I believe shield) to the female receptacle. The original cable was wired directly from pin out to USB A male plug.

From what I understand, I can:

1. Somehow connect S to receptacle (buy a different one?)
2. Leave S unconnected
3. Connect S to receptacle ground

**Edit:**

Here is my keyboard pin out.

[image: keyboard pinout]

Here is my Type C receptacle:

[image: keyboard pinout]

I would like to attach it as a Ducky 2 or Pok3r would connect to a desktop. I wish to replace the current cable with one that is detachable at the keyboard.

[image: like so]

Comment: That sounds like a bad idea; you should probably keep the keyboard a conventional captive USB "A" cable.  If you were really going to try to make it legacy USB over USB C, you'd have to make sure your adapter has the appropriate resistor for the *device* role.

Comment: Are you trying to add a USB C "accessory" port to your keyboard, piggybacked off of the keyboard's USB input(which won't work without an active hub), or are you trying to replace the keyboard's factory USB cable with the USB C female socket?  Please clarify in the question.

Comment: @Hitek I added some photos of what I am working with. I am only trying to replace the current type A cable with a detachable type C cable. Doing so requires I install the female receptacle. The one I have doesnt have a shield hole in the break out.

Comment: @Jtaks - I see, thanks for the clarification.  In your case you should follow the instructions in the first paragraph of my answer.  I have also updated my answer with a photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to replace the USB cable with with the USB C port, then you would simply connect the S pin to the shield of the USB C connector by literally connecting a jumper wire from the S pin to any one of the four shield pins on the bottom(or top, being careful not to let the solder spread away from the bottom of the connector) of the USB C adapter PCB:

[image]

If you are trying to add a USB C "accessory" port to your standard USB keyboard, then active USB hub circuitry will be required, either by designing your own circuit board, or salvaging the circuit board from a donor USB hub and wiring it between the USB-to-host cable, the keyboard circuitry, and the USB C "accessory" port.  You should keep in mind, however, that this configuration is not officially supported by the USB C specification, and may or may not work depending on the hardware, and would also likely require the removal of the two resistors on the USB C board.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The photo is very helpful